# Drawing bitmap to window results in blank screen

Tags: windows, winapi, bitmap, window

I am trying to draw an `HBITMAP` to a window using the Win32 API.

I create the bitmap like this:

```
HBITMAP hBmp = CreateBitmap(bi->biWidth, bi->biHeight, 1, bi->biBitCount, pBits);
```

Then I attempt to draw the bitmap to the window like this:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    Window *pw = (Window *)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);

    if(pw->displayBmp && (pw->bitmap != NULL))
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP oldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, *pw->bitmap);
        BITMAP bmp;
        GetObject(*pw->bitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);

        StretchBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, memDC, 0, 0, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);

        //Cleanup
        SelectObject(memDC, oldBmp);
        DeleteDC(memDC);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    else
        DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

    break;
}
```

Note: The reason I am using GetWindowLong is because I have a Window class of which I have multiple instances. I use GetWindowLong to get the instance of the window class.

The above code just results in the default window color being drawn on the window. What am I doing wrong?

## Solved, answer below

The bitmap I was trying to display was a screenshot. When I took the screenshot, I specified a 24-bit bitmap in the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` which was incorrect as the screen capture was in fact 32-bit. Therefore when trying to display the screenshot, the incorrect bit specification obviously caused a few problems. Setting the bits to 32 in the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure solved my problem.

Comment: How is `pw->bitmap` defined?

Comment: Is there any chance the bitmap is already selected into another DC?

Comment: pw->bitmap is defined as `HBITMAP *bitmap` . The bitmap is not already selected into another DC.

Comment: I guess the only other obvious question is, is `displayBmp` true and is `bitmap` non-NULL?

Comment: Yes, setting a breakpoint inside the if scope verified this. EDIT: After changing the bitmap type to 32-bit, the image is displayed fine apart from the fact that it is upside-down. I should be able to fix this.

Comment: I have edited the question stating the answer.

Comment: Does anyone know why the image is upside-down? I can rectify this by changing the parameters to `StretchBlt` to make it flip it, but it shouldn't be flipped in the first place...

Comment: `GetObject` on a bitmap always returns a positive height, even if the source bitmap is top-down (and therefore has a negative height). This is a limitation of the API.